# getting error when I import the tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jake/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/jake/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/jake/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/jake/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/jake/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/jake/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm trying to install the tensorflow on ubuntu 17. 
Keep getting this error.

I also include the export on ./bashrc file

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

is there other solution to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `cuda 7.5` installed on your system. Then if you do, then may be this will help,

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If it fails too, check the directory using

```
$ ls /usr/local/cuda/
```

See what's in there and modify the command accordingly.

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download which one should I install? and how to check current version of cuda

Comment: nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44

Comment: cuda 7.5 https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-75-downloads-archive and cudnn 5.1 or 6

Comment: I think if you are not, sure enough, follow any tutorial step by step. like this one https://kislayabhi.github.io/Installing_CUDA_with_Ubuntu/

Comment: this happedn  cause of ubuntu 17.04. I downgrade to the 16 version. and it work fine